# Missing Method Exception MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting the following error with the latest MongoDB C# driver.

> System.MissingMethodException MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentationMode
> MongoDB.Bson.BsonDefaults.get_GuidRepresentationMode()

The exception occurs in MongoClient:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://____:___@_____.nrzff.mongodb.net/____?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
var database = client.GetDatabase("ResultsModelSummary");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Zones");   
var bsonDocList = new List<BsonDocument>();
foreach (var r in resModSums) {
    var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(Serialization.Serialize<ResultsModelSummary>(r));
    bsonDocList.Add(bsonDoc);
}

collection.InsertManyAsync(bsonDocList);   

public class ResultsModelSummary
    {
        // META
        public string RunID { get; set; } // this is a stringified GUID
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
        // more fields .....
    }
```

**The exception actually occurs irregularly. Sometimes the above code works fine.**

Any suggestions?

**Adding more information:**

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513   Message=Method
> not found: 'MongoDB.Bson.GuidRepresentationMode
> MongoDB.Bson.BsonDefaults.get_GuidRepresentationMode()'.
> Source=MongoDB.Driver   StackTrace:    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)    at
> EnergyMLGH.MongoDB.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0() in
> C:\Users...\MongoDB.cs:line
> 52    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

[image: Screenshot of exception]

Comment: do you use reflection?

Comment: what's your use case? I don't think that creating a client itself can trigger this error

Comment: @dododo thanks for your quick response. Yes, I believe I use reflection under the hood in the serialization process. I am serializing my "ResultModelSummary" class using JSON.net and then parse as BSONDocument. The RunID is a GUID formatted string.

Comment: I'm still not sure what happens exactly under the scene in your serialization steps. Can you provide the exact code that triggers this issue?

Comment: *I mean inner steps from `Serialization.Serialize`

Comment: Serialization.Serialize uses just calls into Newtonsoft's JSON.Net and produces a string that looks like this: {
  "RunID": "3b9dfe15-38af-49eb-a986-34030bbd0c54",
  "TimeStamp": "8/27/2020 5:28:47 PM",
  ...
} The debugger throws the exception on the MongoClient line...

Comment: >The debugger throws the exception on the MongoClient line...
wait, you mean that creating MongoClient (the first line in your code) throws? And all other repro lines are not called at all?

Comment: Yes - I find this very strange and I thought this is related to the stringified GUID ("RunID") as I noticed this happening after I added that field. However, since the debugger throws the exception inside "new MongoClient(..." I think this cannot be related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220590/discussion-between-dododo-and-timkado).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that I had MongoDB references with different versions. I removed the references and added them back, making sure that the versions were all the latest ones and voila, it started working.